# What are the spring provided components?

Tags: spring

I m reading a book about spring 5 certifications.

I have read the following sentence `The Spring Framework IoC component is the nucleus of the framework. It uses dependency injection to assemble Spring-provided (also called infrastructure components) and development-provided components to rapidly wrap up an application`.

I believe that **development-provided components** are my annotated java classes that will be injected using DI for example a @Controller or a @Repository.

However I m curious about the second part: **Infrastructure Components**. what are these. where they are being injected ? can I consider the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` an Infrastructure Component or are they referencing to another thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the completion of this book chapter

I conclude that some provided spring components that bootstraps the spring application are like below:

- org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
- org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
- org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor

and more .